# wxWidgets : non blocking copy to FTP

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to copy a file to a FTP server using wxFTP, but I would like to do this without blocking the UI, and much better, while displaying a progress bar. Can I do this without extra thread?

I'm using wxLua, but I can adapt a solution written in any language as long as it uses a wxWidgets binding.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **wx.lib.delayedresult**. It's available in wxPython, but maybe also it is in your wxWidgets library too. It creates separate worker thread and is called with a  *consumer* function that is called once worker thread finishes his job. Quite useful thing.

See [wxPython docs](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.delayedresult-module.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with starting your own Thread for this?

You could check the streams `canRead()` method periodically (through a timer or in the event loop, maybe) and only read when it returns true, but it'll probably be a lot more complex than just starting a separate thread.

Comment: I just wondered if I could do this with wxFTP, as I can do this with wxSocket*